# Create notifications only bot for Microsoft Teams

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I'm trying to create a notifier via MS Teams.  I want to send a direct message to a named user.  Here's what I've done so far:

1. Created a bot at https://dev.botframework.com in my azure account
2. Tied the bot to an app registration in AzureAD
3. Retrieved a token

I'm trying to create a new conversation by posting:

```
{
  "bot": {
    "name": "OpenUnison Notifications Bot",
    "id": "openunison"
  },
  "members": [
    {
      "name": "Matt Mosley",
      "id": "mmosley@marcboorshteintremolosecuri.onmicrosoft.com"
    }
  ],
  "topicName": "OpenUnison Notifications",
  "isGroup": false
}
```

to https://smba.trafficmanager.net/apis/v3/conversations, the response I get is

```
{"error":{"code":"BadSyntax","message":"Bad format of conversation ID"}}
```

When I look in the activity log I don't see anything for the Teams channel, but for web I see `Activity dropped because the bot's endpoint is missing`.  I think I'm missing something.  I don't want to handle responses, this is a no-reply notifications only bot.  How can I avoid requiring a bot endpoint?  Also, am I even taking the right approach for my goal?

Answer (score 1):

Notification-only bots use [proactive messaging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/resources/bot-v3/bot-conversations/bots-conv-proactive) to communicate with the user.
A proactive message is a message that is sent by a bot to start a conversation.
When using proactive messaging to send notifications you need to make sure your users have a clear path to take common actions based on your notification, and a clear understanding of why the notification occurred.

```
POST {Service URL of your bot}/v3/conversations
    {
  "bot": {
    "id": "c38eda0f-e780-49ae-86f0-afb644203cf8",
    "name": "The Bot"
  },
  "members": [
    {
      "id": "29:012d20j1cjo20211"
    }
  ],
  "channelData": {
    "tenant": {
      "id": "197231joe-1209j01821-012kdjoj"
    }
  }
}
```

Sample Link-https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-teams-sample-complete-csharp/blob/32c39268d60078ef54f21fb3c6f42d122b97da22/template-bot-master-csharp/src/dialogs/examples/teams/ProactiveMsgTo1to1Dialog.cs

Comment: Thanks, this is really helpful.  I'm missing a couple of things though:
1. how do i lookup a team member by their UPN on Email address?  I have graph API access, but that id format doesn't match anything I've seen in the graph API
2. which tenant id?  As in my AzureAD tenant id?

thanks!

Comment: Also, where do I get the bot id?  I don't see anything that looks like what you provided when I look at the bot in the Azure console.

Comment: You got the value from here as mentioned in example -
bots TurnContext object such as turnContext.Activity.From.Id. Similarly, id of tenant, from your bots TurnContext object such as turnContext.Activity.ChannelData.Tenant.Id.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/resources/bot-v3/bot-conversations/bots-conv-proactive#examples

Sample Link- https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-teams-sample-complete-csharp/blob/32c39268d60078ef54f21fb3c6f42d122b97da22/template-bot-master-csharp/src/dialogs/examples/teams/ProactiveMsgTo1to1Dialog.cs